DriveItem Patch method with error in Graph Api
I'm creating an API with ASP.NET Core that accesses a list/drive with the graph api and at some point I need to update an item that was created in the drive library to add an ID (which is a custom column), but I'm getting an invalid request error, can anyone help me?
EDIT: I found the problem, apparently it doesn't recognize the additonal fields, when I put only Name it works. How can I update custom fields?
        public async Task<DriveItem?> CreateDriveItem(FileDTO file)
        {
            var fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(file.Base64);
            var fileNameWithExtension = file.FileName + file.FileType;

            var requestBody = new CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody
            {
                Item = new DriveItemUploadableProperties
                {
                    Name = fileNameWithExtension,
                }
            };

            var uploadSession = await _graphClient.Graph.Drives[_driveId].Root.ItemWithPath(fileNameWithExtension).CreateUploadSession.PostAsync(requestBody);

            if (uploadSession == null) { return null; }

            using var stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
            await UploadFileInChunks(uploadSession.UploadUrl ?? "", stream);

            var createdItem = await _graphClient.Graph.Drives[_driveId].Root.ItemWithPath(fileNameWithExtension).GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "listItem($expand=fields)" };
            });

            if (createdItem == null) { return null; }

            var requestBodyPatch = new DriveItem
            {
                Name = "NomeAtualizado com ID.txt",
                ListItem = new ListItem
                {
                    Fields = new FieldValueSet
                    {
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            {"ID_Solicitacao", 123 }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var patch = await _graphClient.Graph.Drives[_driveId].Items[createdItem.Id].PatchAsync(requestBodyPatch);

            if (patch == null) { return null; }

            return patch;
        }

and the error is:
{
  "message": "OData error occurred.",
  "details": "Cannot update a listItem via driveItem, patch the listItem directly"
}



In a SharePoint document library, each item is composed of both a DriveItem and a ListItem, which are linked together. To update such an item, you follow these steps:
Upload the Document:
First, you upload the document. The response from this upload will include the created DriveItem.
var uploadSession = await_graphClient.Graph.Drives[_driveId].Root.ItemWithPath(fileNameWithExtension).CreateUploadSession.PostAsync(requestBody);

Retrieve the ListItem ID:
The DriveItem response contains a property called listItem. This listItem property includes an id, which is the ID of the linked ListItem.
var createdItem = await _graphClient.Graph.Drives[_driveId].Root.ItemWithPath(fileNameWithExtension).GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "listItem($expand=fields)" };
});

createdItem.ListItem?.Id

Update the ListItem:
Using the listItemId, you can directly update the fields of the ListItem without needing to search for it.
var fields = new FieldValueSet
    {
      AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
          {"ID_Solicitacao", 123 }
        }
    };
  
var patch = await _graphClient.Graph.Sites[_siteId].Lists[_driveListId].Items[createdItem.ListItem?.Id].Fields.PatchAsync(fields);

This method ensures you can efficiently upload a document and update its associated ListItem fields using the provided ID from the upload response.
